# Django custom user model with different user models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am creating a school management system and I want that when the admin creates users using the custom user model, the admin should create users and their profiles same time but profiles have different profile models

I dont know what is it that I am doing wrong. I have a custom user model and also 3 different models for different users as below

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_parent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

The other model is

```
class AdminHOD(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=4, default=MR, choices=TITLE, blank=False, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField()
    gender = models.CharField(_('Gender'), max_length=20, default=MALE, choices=GENDER, blank=False)
    tel = models.CharField(default='+273240000000', null = False, blank=False, max_length=15, help_text= 'Enter number with Country Code Eg. +273240000000')
    birthday = models.DateField(_('Birthday'), blank=False, null=False)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="avatars/adminhod/")
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(_('Address Line 1'), max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(_('Address Line 2'), max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(_('City'), max_length=125, null=True, blank=True)
    province = models.CharField(_('Province'), max_length=40, default=GAUTENG, choices=PROVINCES, blank=False, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Created'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Updated'), auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('AdminHOD')
        verbose_name_plural = _('AdminHODs')
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

I also have `signals.py` as:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        if instance.is_staff or instance.is_superuser:
            AdminHOD.objects.update_or_create(
                user=instance, 
                bio=instance.adminhod.bio, 
                avatar=instance.adminhod.avatar, 
                title=instance.adminhod.title,
                gender=instance.adminhod.gender,
                tel=instance.adminhod.tel,
                birthday=instance.adminhod.birthday,
                address_line_1=instance.adminhod.address_line_1,
                address_line_2=instance.adminhod.address_line_2,
                city=instance.adminhod.city,
                province=instance.adminhod.province,
        )


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
  if instance.is_staff or instance.is_superuser:
    instance.adminhod.save()
```

My create view looks like this

```
def AdminHODCreationView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = AdminHODForm(request.POST)
        admin_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user.admin_profile = admin_profile
            user.save()

            email = user.email
            first_name = user.first_name
            last_name = user.last_name
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {first_name} {last_name} as admin')
            return redirect('admin_users')
    else:
        user_form = CustomUserCreationForm()
        profile_form = AdminHODForm()

    context = {
        'title': 'Add New Admin',
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    }
    return render(request, 'adminHOD/add_adminhod.html', context)
```

When I create the user it doesn't get created. What am I missing?

Comment: I would imagine `if user_form.is_valid():` is not true, but you're not handling that case.

Comment: I have added the else to return error but it still not working